# Gravitational waves parallel

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, acoustics, gravitational-waves

Just an idea to illustrate the gravitational waves. This kind of analogy is proposed:

> - When you have a rotational motion of the fluid, some small amount of the energy is radiated as a pressure wave ([Lighthill's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroacoustics) etc.), beside the convective motions.
> - When you have a temperature difference, some amount of heat transfer is done by EM waves ([Thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation)), beside the convection and diffusion.
> - When a large body moves, some amount of the gravitational interaction is done as a wave, beside the non-wave curvature effects.

Essentially, it can't be fully correct (different propagation media, different math-based origin etc.). But how good/bad is this analogy? Is there any illustrative sense or it's wildly misleading? How could it be corrected?

Comment: The question is what you need these analogs for? There is a fairly well worked out theory of gravitational waves, certainly in the weak field regime,  so we don't have to guess how these waves behave. Unlike full general relativity the linearized field equations on a flat (or only slightly curved) background metric are fairly easy to understand. The theory is not significantly more complex than in the case of electromagnetic waves, so one might as well use it. Now, the hard part, the description of the sources of these waves, that's a different matter, but for those the analogs won't help.